# How to access individual elements of a list when using pipe operator?

Tags: elixir

I am sending a list through pipe operator and would like to do something with individual elements.  But don't know how to access each elements.  Here is an example

```
[1,[[2],3]] |> List.flatten |> how do I multiply each element with 2

[1,[[2],3]] |> List.flatten |> &(&1 * 2) #=> error...can only pipe into local calls
```

tried couple of other variations that didn't work.  I am missing something very very important here.

```
[1,[[2],3]] |> List.flatten |> &(&1 * 2).()
[1,[[2],3]] |> List.flatten |> (fn(x)-> x*2 end).()
```

Comment: You mean `Enum.map/2`? `[1,[[2],3]] |> List.flatten |> Enum.map(&(&1 * 2)) #=> [2, 4, 6]`

Comment: Aha. So I need to use a method such as `Enum.map` to iterate and do something with it.

Comment: `Enum.map` if you want to transform each element seperately. `Enum.each` if you want to use them for side effects, `Enum.reduce` or `Enum.reduce_while` if you want to reduce them.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer @Dogbert

Comment: @Bala Is that a typo on those last two code snippets?  I mean after List.flatten did you mean to type `|` as opposed to `|>`?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: Thanks. Yes it was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're looking for [`Enum.map/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2):

```
[1,[[2],3]]
|> List.flatten
|> Enum.map(&(&1 * 2))    # => [2, 4, 6]
```

Another option is to use [`Enum.each/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#each/2), when you have "to just do something" with the List items without returning anything.

---

### **Understanding Pipe Operator**

From your question, I also feel that you don't fully understand how to use the Pipe Operator. Using a Pipe operator, you "feed" the result of the previous statement into the next function as its first argument.

**From the Elixir Website:**

> **[Enumerables and Streams - The Pipe Operator](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#the-pipe-operator)**
>
> [The Pipe Operator] takes the output from the expression on its left side and passes it as the first argument to the function call on its right side. It’s similar to the Unix | operator. Its purpose is to highlight the data being transformed by a series of functions

Here's an example:

```
list = [1,[[2],3]]
flattened_list = List.flatten(list)
doubled_list = Enum.map(flattened_list, fn i -> i*2 end)
```

When using the Pipe operator, it looks like this:

```
[1,[[2],3]]
|> List.flatten
|> Enum.map(fn i -> i*2 end)
```